# how to communicate between an application on a mobile (android) and an application on a PC (java swing)?

Tags: java, android, rest, soap, xml-rpc

I have two application (java) on two PCs and a mobile application (Android)
the mobile application can be on an iPhone ...

My problem is the interaction between different applications with the database:
- Between PC and PC (two application **java-swing**)
- PC and mobile

PC(n°1)<--------->serveur(BD)<------------>PC(n°2)--------->serveur(Web)------>mobile

app1 <---------> MySQL <--------------->app2 --------->(XML-RPC ou SOAP ou REST) -------->app3

how to use a web service in eclipse ?
-I thought about using **SOAP** or **XML-RPC** or **REST** but I do not know where to start I use (eclipse-java-indigo-SR1) as editor.
-between two PCs I use MySQL as a server.
Can you explain what exactly I must do, I need realement realize it.

XML-RPC how to use this library and I do not understand how it works and exactly where i use it.

```
  XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://foo.bar.com");
// add 2 to 4
int sum = (Integer) client.call("add", 2, 4);
// check whether x is inside range 4..10
boolean isInside = (Boolean) client.call("isInside", x, 4, 10);
// capitalize string
String capitalized = (String) client.call("capitalize", "to be or not to be");
```

XML-RPC or SOAP or REST ?which the simplest and most effective?

Comment: Your question does not have an answer :) Just pick one that you 'like' and go from there.

Comment: thank you my question is very difficult :)